# How to get var from Android webview

Tags: android, webview

I Want to get the value of **`resPG`** from webview after it load this page

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    var resPG = {status: '<?php echo $status;?>', msg: '<?php echo $msg;?>', trans_no: '<?php echo $Tran_ID;?>', pay_amt: '<?php echo $Amount;?>', pg_type: '<?php echo $Tran_Type;?>', billno: '<?php echo $RRN;?>', PAN: '<?php echo $PAN;?>'};   
    localStorage.setItem('resPG', JSON.stringify(resPG));
});
</script>
```

Comment: Could you please explain bit more with your analysis.

Comment: @RajPaliwal i want to get **resPG** value from my apps in webview . resPG  load value and i want to get the value .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to create a [Javascript](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/JavascriptInterface) interface for get values from web to android native. for working example click [this](https://github.com/googlearchive/chromium-webview-samples/tree/master/jsinterface-example) link

step1)
Enable webview setting

```
WebView mWebView = findViewById(R.id.myWebView);
mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
mWebView.setWebChromeClient(new MyWebChromeClient((Activity)mContext));
mWebView.addJavascriptInterface(new testClass(), "jsinterface");
mWebView.loadUrl("UrlToLoad");
```

create interface :

```
public class testClass{
    public testClass() {
    }

    @JavascriptInterface
    public void getvalues(value) {
       Log.i('web view value',value)
    }
}
```

step 3:
add interface function inside JS

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var resPG = {status: '<?php echo $status;?>', msg: '<?php echo $msg;?>', trans_no: '<?php echo $Tran_ID;?>', pay_amt: '<?php echo $Amount;?>', pg_type: '<?php echo $Tran_Type;?>', billno: '<?php echo $RRN;?>', PAN: '<?php echo $PAN;?>'};   
    localStorage.setItem('resPG', JSON.stringify(resPG));
jsinterface.getvalues(resPG );
});
```

another way is for better handling

```
if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
                webView.evaluateJavascript("{status: '<?php echo $status;?>', msg: '<?php echo $msg;?>', trans_no: '<?php echo $Tran_ID;?>', pay_amt: '<?php echo $Amount;?>', pg_type: '<?php echo $Tran_Type;?>', billno: '<?php echo $RRN;?>', PAN: '<?php echo $PAN;?>'};", new ValueCallback<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onReceiveValue(String s) {
                        contentView.setText(s);
                    }
                });
            }
            else {
                webView.loadUrl("javascript:window.jsinterface.getvalues({status: '<?php echo $status;?>', msg: '<?php echo $msg;?>', trans_no: '<?php echo $Tran_ID;?>', pay_amt: '<?php echo $Amount;?>', pg_type: '<?php echo $Tran_Type;?>', billno: '<?php echo $RRN;?>', PAN: '<?php echo $PAN;?>'};)");

            }
```

Comment: getvalues(value) ? value

Comment: getvalues is your javascript interface function

Comment: **Not Working **

Comment: check now and revert

Comment: getting null value

Comment: create one function with ur logic in your html file and call that function

Answer (score 1):

You can use JavaScript scheme in web-view load URL something like below

```
webview.loadUrl("javascript:Android.getMyData(MyData);");

//Add the javascript interface to your web view
this.addJavascriptInterface(new MyJavaScriptInterface(webViewContext), "Android");

public class MyJavaScriptInterface{
    Context mContext;

    /** Instantiate the interface and set the context */
    CustomJavaScriptInterface(Context c) {
        mContext = c;
    }


    /** retrieve the data */
    public void getMyData(final String myData) {

        //Do somethings with the Data

}
```